# perl execution permission error

Tags: sql, sql-server, perl, perl-module

I have one perl script using this script connect sqlserver database and execute a stored procedure in this case perl scrip give one error
scrip is

```
use DBI;
my $host = 'server';
my $database = 'db';
my $user = 'usr';
my $auth = 'pssword';
# DBD::ADO
$dsn = "Provider=sqloledb;Trusted Connection=yes;";
$dsn .= "Server=$host;Database=$database";
my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:ADO:$dsn",
$user,
$auth,
{ RaiseError => 1, AutoCommit => 1}
) || die "Database connection not made: $DBI::errstr";

my $sql = "EXEC [dbo].[get_status] '2013-10-31','00',320,'MBM40CASHFLW'";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();
$sth->finish();
$dbh->disconnect();
```

above script i use dbi:ado driver. I give full grand permissions in this stored procedure

errors is

```
DBD::ADO::st execute failed: Can't execute statement 'EXEC [dbo].[sap.get_status_load_data] '2013-10-31','00!',320,'MBMY_FCL_S40CASHFLW''
Lasterror:       -2147217871: OLE exception from "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server":

Query timeout expired

Win32::OLE(0.1709) error 0x80040e31
    in METHOD/PROPERTYGET "Execute"
        Description:    Query timeout expired
        HelpContext:    0
        HelpFile:
        NativeError:    0
        Number:         -2147217871
        Source:         Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server
        SQLState:       HYT00 at C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\temp\testdbconn.pl line 19.
```

**Please help me .....**

Comment: So does this query respond outside of Perl? Does it work via the same mechanism elsewhere?

Comment: using sqlcmd it's working

Comment: outside commands it is working

Comment: please give same solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the timeout attributes?  Perhaps:

```
{ RaiseError => 1, AutoCommit => 1,  ado_ConnectionTimeout => 300, CommandTimeout => 300}
```

(depending on what your current timeouts are).